# RxJava: how to turn a complicated if statement into a reactive stream?

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I am implementing an app introduction and waiver that should appear before the user can access the `MainActivity` of my Android app. If the user has not accepted the waiver or gone through the app introduction, then my `IntroNavigator` kicks them back to those activities.

How can I rxify my `redirectIfNecessary()` method in a more functional manner, instead of the imperative approach I implemented below.

**IntroNavigatorImpl.java**

```
public class IntroNavigatorImpl implements IntroNavigator {
    WeakReference<Activity> activityWeakReference;
    CloudPrefsRepo cloudPrefsRepo;

    public IntroNavigatorImpl(Activity activity, CloudPrefsRepo cloudPrefsRepo) {
        this.activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        this.cloudPrefsRepo = cloudPrefsRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public void redirectIfNecessary() {
        final boolean shouldShowAppIntro = cloudPrefsRepo.shouldShowAppIntro()
           .toObservable().toBlocking().first();
        final boolean shouldShowWaiver = cloudPrefsRepo.shouldShowWaiver()
           .toObservable().toBlocking().first();

        if (shouldShowAppIntro) {
            showAppIntro();
            finishActivity();
        } else if (shouldShowWaiver) {
            showWaiver();
            finishActivity();
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void showWaiver() {
        //launch waiver activity
    }

    @Override
    public void showAppIntro() {
        //launch app intro activity
    }

    public void finishActivity() {
        if (activityWeakReference.get() != null) {
            activityWeakReference.get().finish();
        }
    }
}
```

**CloudPrefsRepo.java**

```
public interface 
    /**
     * Whether to show the app intro.
     */
    Single<Boolean> shouldShowAppIntro();

    /**
     * Whether to show the waiver. If the user has already 
     * accepted this waiver, then it shouldn't be shown.
     */
    Single<Boolean> shouldShowWaiver();
```

Comment: RxJava is awesome library, but don't you think that "rxifying" this method could be over-engineering? We shouldn't put RxJava everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Edit Based on comment:

It's not the prettiest (I'm leaning towards there not being a good reactive way to do this)

```
final Action0 showInfoAction = new Action0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            showAppIntro();
            finishActivity();
        }
    };


    final Action0 showWaiverAction = new Action0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            showWaiver();
            finishActivity();
        }
    };

    final Action0 blankAction = new Action0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {

        }
    };

    Observable.zip(shouldShowInfo, shouldShowWaiver, new Func2<Boolean, Boolean,  Action0>() {
        @Override
        public  Action0 call(Boolean shoudlShowInfo, Boolean shouldShowWaiver) {
            if (shoudlShowInfo) {
                return showInfoAction;
            } else if (shouldShowWaiver) {
                return showWaiverAction;
            } else {
                return blankAction;
            }
        }
    }).subscribe(new Action1<Action0>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Action0 action0) {
            action0.call();
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks. But the issue is that only the **AppIntro** OR the **Waiver** can be shown at a time. On first app load both the appIntro and waiver would return true.

the waiver observable should be ignored, unless the appIntro observable returns false. I am not sure how to express that dependency in Rx

Comment: see revised answer above